# Correct way to check if JavaFX MediaPlayer can play a file

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, java-9, audio-player

Currently, this is how I check if a file is playable through the JavaFX MediaPlayer, since it's the way it is done internally.

```
import static com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayContentType;
import static com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MediaUtils.filenameToContentType;

public boolean isPlayable(String filename) {
    return canPlayContentType(filenameToContentType(filename));
}
```

the problem is that the packages that contain these Methods "are not API" and not accessible on Java 9 anymore. I know that there are workarounds, but I wonder if there is an actually correct, future-proof way of doing this?

I want this method to populate a Library with all the playable content within a directory:

```
Files.find(folderPath, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attr) -> 
        attr.isRegularFile() && isPlayable(path.toFile().getName()))
        .forEach(path -> addSong(path));
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the documentation of [`javafx.media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx.media-summary.html) module for the sake of finding any such built-in API and was unable to find one.

---

A look at the existing Implementation of `filenameToContentType(String filename)`, which is somewhat:-

```
if (extension.equals(FILE_TYPE_AIF) || extension.equals(FILE_TYPE_AIFF)) {
    contentType = CONTENT_TYPE_AIFF;
} else if ... other content types
```

That eventually checks if the current file extension is one of [the supported container type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes) and returns the content types based on the same.

The other piece on the board crucially was `canPlayContentType(String contentType)` which seems to be relying eventually on the `supportedContentTypes` for each platform as defined in the `NativeMediaManager` class.

---

Though I haven't tested the solution as proposed below primarily due to unawareness of the overview of the task that you intend to perform eventually. Yet, the closest to your current implementation and what *[Basic PlayBack guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#PlayingMediaInJavaFX)* suggests as well, was to try

- Construct a [`Media` instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-) out of the filename that you were providing.
- Check for a [`MediaException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaException.html) if any while performing (1).

---

Further, the exception type `MediaException.Type MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED` states that

> Indicates that this media type is not supported by this platform.

Drawing from the analogy with this and your current solution, you could probably make use of the this:

```
private static boolean isPlayable(String filename) {
    try {
        Media media = new Media(filename);
    } catch (MediaException e) {
        if (e.getType() == MediaException.Type.MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

***PS***: Though I believe this could be further optimized if you actually start making use of the `Media` constructed(as in the above stub) right away in your piece of code instead of just dropping it.

Comment: Yeah I kinda already thought of that, though I don't think that catching an Exception should be the preferred way to handle this. Now, since I store a whole Library of Objects, which can be up to 40,000 in some instances, I wonder whether a File Object or a Media Object has the larger memory footprint.

Comment: I've now encountered a big issue: The Media object locks the corresponding file, which prevents me from reading its Tags directly after that...

Comment: @Xerus not sure, of what the final implementation you ended up with, can we have another question for that though(just asking to avoid any indirectly related question maybe)?